# Groovy: Appending to large files

Tags: groovy, file-writing

How do I append to large files efficiently. I have a process that has to continually append to a file and as the file size grows the performance seems to slow down as well. Is there anyway to specify a large buffer size with the `append`

Comment: Groovy easily accepts Java syntax and is on the JVM, so the question can be posed 'how do I append to large files efficiently using the GDK or JDK ?' The first answer below uses this logic.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

While Don's approach is valid, in general (it will throw an exception, though, because of a syntax error, and you need to `flush()` a `BufferedOutputStream`), I've been planning to elaborate further (which takes its time).

Groovy [does not provide](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/io/package-summary.html) special objects for I/O operations. Thus, you would use Java's [`FileOutputStream`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html) (for writing bytes) or [`FileWriter`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html) (for writing strings). Both provide a constructor that takes a `boolean` `append` parameter.
For both, there exist *decorators* ([`BufferedOutputStream`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedOutputStream.html) and [`BufferedWriter`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html)), which are buffered. "Buffering", in this scope, means, that contents are not necessarily written instantly to the underlying stream, and thus, there's a potential for I/O optimization.

Don already provided a sample for the `BufferedOutputStream`, and here's one for the `BufferedWriter`:

```
File file = new File("foo")
if (file.exists()) {
    assert file.delete()
    assert file.createNewFile()
}

boolean append = true
FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file, append)
BufferedWriter buffWriter = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter)

100.times { buffWriter.write "foo" }

buffWriter.flush()
buffWriter.close()
```

While Groovy does not provide its own I/O objects, the [Groovy JDK (GDK)](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/) enhances several Java types by adding convenience methods. In the scope of I/O outputting, the [`OutputStream`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/io/OutputStream.html) and the [`File`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/io/File.html) types are relevant.

So, finally, you can work with those the "Groovy way":

```
new File("foo").newOutputStream().withWriter("UTF-8") { writer ->
    100.times { writer.write "foo" + it }
}
```

---

**EDIT:** As per your further inquiry:

None of the GDK methods allows for setting a buffer size.

The above "Groovy" code will *overwrite* the file if called repeatedly. - In contrast, the following piece of code will append the string to an *existing* file and, thus, *can* be called repeatedly:

```
new File("foo").withWriterAppend("UTF-8") { it.write("bar") }
```

Comment: This is fine if I am appending to the file in one swoop. If the file is existing already, will this work as well? Also in the groovy way how would I specify a buffer size?

Answer (score 0):

```
def file = new File('/path/to/file')

// Create an output stream that writes to the file in 'append' mode
def fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(file, true)

// Buffer the output - set bufferSize to whatever size buffer you want to use
def bufferSize = 512
def fileOutput = new BufferedOutputStream(fileOutput, bufferSize)

try {
    byte[] contentToAppend = // Get the content to write to the file
    fileOutput.write(contentToAppend)
} finally {
    fileOutput.close()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the JVM on Windows the `append` flag has been implemented inefficently with a seek operation.

This is neighter atomic nor very performant when opening the file multiple times. It is supposed to be fixed somewhere in the Java VM 7: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6631352